# Popup javascript shown in python login page

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

I am so new with python and I am making a login page, the front-end is with HTML,CSS, JS and backend is with python and everything works fine, Now I want to have a popup javascript code shown when the user entered the wrong password, my codes are ready but I don't know how to connect javascript to python and also show the popup.
Now I return a static message when user entered the wrong password:
any help really appreciated. :)

> My javascript popup code:
>   [Source Code from JS](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

```
let timerInterval
Swal.fire({
 title: 'You entered wrong username or password',
 html: 'I will close in <b></b> milliseconds.',
 timer: 2000,
 timerProgressBar: true,
 onBeforeOpen: () => {
  Swal.showLoading()
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
   const content = Swal.getContent()
   if (content) {
    const b = content.querySelector('b')
    if (b) {
     b.textContent = Swal.getTimerLeft()
    }
   }
  }, 100)
 },
 onClose: () => {
  clearInterval(timerInterval)
 }
}).then((result) => {
 /* Read more about handling dismissals below */
 if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.timer) {
  console.log('I was closed by the timer')
 }
})
```

> My Python Code : When login fails

```
        return (login_result)
        if login_result == '0':
            return('Successful')
        elif login_result != '0':
            return('invalid credentials')
```

> My HTML Code : for login button

```
<div>
   <button>
   Login
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the JS code connected to the back-end code?

Comment: This is my exact question, sorry if this is so basic:-(

Comment: I dont know how to connect and also show the popup.

Comment: My post has been updated.

Comment: What I don't get is how `login_result` is set, for example. Can you also show the whole Python code for the login?

Comment: The request method is post and username and password calls a webservice to be checked if it is wrong or right, if the username password exist and is correct it will allow to login , but with wrong authentication no! so i just want to show the failure message of login in a javascript popup.

Comment: I'd need to see the Python code for that webservice login to be able to help you then.. and show how the JS calls this service as well.

Comment: This doesn't belong here, but you've asked me something and then deleted the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62245567/evaluatexpath-runs-slow-for-repeating-1-xml-element-in-java?noredirect=1#comment110102836_62245567). Undelete, if you still care, otherwise consider undeleting as it might be useful for others.

Comment: @maaartinus Sure I undelete it. I thought maybe it's better to ask question in other way  and alittle scared of closing the next one because of duplication.Thanks for the time you share for the issue.