# evaluateXPath runs slow for repeating 1 XML Element in java

Tags: java, arrays, performance, xpath, java-stream

I have about 1,000,000 XML files and I am using XpathExpression with Java language to walk through the XML tags and get my considered data.

Imagine I have about 5000 tags for name, 5000 tags for family name, 5000 tags for age, and only 1 tag for date in each file. Now I want to repeat date tag to 5000 times too.

Blow code is runnable for XML files with Java programming with less than 20MB size, but I have files with more than 20MB size and it takes so many times to run and in some cases, I got Out of memory error in eclipse( I tried adding vmargs in the run configuration of Eclipse but it takes so much time and still so low.) 
I am pretty sure there is a problem with my array for repeting date tag and it is not optimized, I really appreciate if you mind and have a look at my code, in addition I should say that i am newbie to java:

```
package TEST;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Data {

    //function started
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
        //Get Files
            String doc ="MyFileNew";
            String dump="";
            int number =200;
            for (int i=1; i<=201; i++) {
               number ++;
               dump = doc+number;
               String fileName= "/root/MyFiles/" + dump + ".xml";
               Document document = getDocument(fileName);
;
               FileWriter fw = null; 
               BufferedWriter bw = null; 
               PrintWriter pw = null;


                //Using Document Builder
                DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc1 = documentBuilder.parse(fileName);


             /*******Get attribute values using xpath******/
            XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();


            try {
                fw = new FileWriter("/root/Results/" + dump + ".txt");
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                pw = new PrintWriter(bw);


                //Printing Name tags
                pw.println( "Name"+ evaluateXPath(document, "/xml/item/item[@key='Name']/text()") );


                 //Counting Name tags
                XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("count(/xml/item/item[@key='Name']/)");
                Number result1 = (Number) expr1.evaluate(doc1, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
                int n = result1.intValue(); 

                //Printing FamilyName tags
                pw.println( "FamilyName: " + evaluateXPath(document, "/xml/item/item[@key='FamilyName']/text() \n") );

                //Printing Age tags
                pw.println( "Age: " + evaluateXPath(document, "/xml/item/item[@key='Age']/text() \n") );

                //Repeating Date based on counting name tags

                String[] strArray = new String[0];
                for (int q=0; q<n;q++){
                List<String> strArraytmp = evaluateXPath(document,"/xml/item/item[@key='date']/text()");
                String[] strings = strArraytmp.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
                strArray= Stream.of(strArray, strings ).flatMap(Stream::of).toArray(String[]::new); 
                  }
                pw.println("date: " + Arrays.toString(strArray));

                System.out.println("this file goes to path:" + "/root/Results/Data/" + dump + ".txt");
                pw.flush();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { e.printStackTrace(); } } 

}
        private static List<String> evaluateXPath(Document document, String xpathExpression) throws Exception 
        {
            // Create XPathFactory object
            XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

            // Create XPath object
            XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

            List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
            try
            {
                // Create XPathExpression object
                XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);

                // Evaluate expression result on XML document
                NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    values.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
                }

            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return values;
        }


        private static Document getDocument(String fileName) throws Exception 
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(fileName);
            return doc;
        }

        }
```

Comment: You're using `DocumentBuilder.parse(...)`, which is DOM-based, meaning the entire XML gets loaded into memory and parsed onto an object model. Since you're facing memory issues, I'd recommend to switching to SAX-based processing, which traverses the document element by element instead

Comment: can i use with XPath in SAX also? or i should rebuild all my code?

Comment: Also would you mind please have a quick look at this  [link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/xpath/java-xpath-performance-dom-vs-sax-example/) , in the conslusion it said SAX Parser are slower than DOM?

Comment: No idea why they claim that SAX parsers are slower than DOM parsers, but IMHO SAX is the right approach - assuming it can do what you need. If you can extract all needed information in a single pass, it'll probably be simple and fast. Imagine going through the file with a pencil and underlining everything you need... that's about how it works.

Comment: @CodeGirl they may or may not be slower, but in your case, a DOM parser empirically proved memory prohibitive. Your point being...?

Comment: @crizzis when I run this program without for of array for repeating date, the code works fine, Is there any way to improve this array or use something else like threadpool in java?

Comment: @maaartinus With your clear explanation, I completely understand thepoint. Now is it possible to improve this code and not rebuild it in SAX? cause this code works properly without FOR array loop of repeating date tag and with adding the loop it becomes so slow. I searched yesterday and i knew SAX can not work with Xpath so I should rebuild  and i think it takes s much time:-(

Comment: @maaartinus their claim is based on ignoring the cost of parsing for the DOM parser. Of course, this only makes sense if you are searching the same document over and over again and keep the DOM tree in memory between the operations.

Comment: In case you want to stick with DOM, move some object creations out of the loop, as you need only one such things (I don't recall the details, but I guess, `DocumentBuilderFactory` is expensive to create and can be reused. Also avoid needless copying like `strArraytmp` to array and then to stream - you can stream the list directly/ That all said, these are minor optimizations which won't save you.

Comment: The problem is that a SAX parser is very different - you practically start anew. It's also rather confusing to get called with every tiny thing rather than simply collecting what you want. Anyway, I 'd bet that it wins hands down concerning speed. Concerning memory, there's nothing to bet. ATM I don't have the time to tell you more, but try find a good SAX tutorial.